# mini Tesla PN2222A transistor getting hot

Tags: transistors

I am helping my son make a mini-Tesla for his science fair project and came across a problem I can't figure out.  I am following this diagram (pretty much, but without the LED):

[image]

Also, I am not sure of the exact number of windings - around 300 of 27 AWG wire.  I have experimented with 2 to 6 primary coil windings and can make this work with 3 windings of the primary coil. My problem is that I have burned up two transistors already - not right away, the circuit works and I can turn a bulb on but the transistor is getting VERY hot.  Why?  Do I need

1. fewer or more primary windings?
2. a different type of transistor?
3. a heatsink?
4. a different value resistor or an additional resistor or capacitor (don't ask, but I have seen other versions of this mini Tesla)
5. just need to buy more tansistors and hope for the best?

Thanks in advance.

LTR

Comment: Is the switch physical or electronic?

Comment: The switch is a physical switch.

Comment: If you wind the transformer the wrong way, does the mini-Tesla still work?

Answer (score 2):

See [Understanding the slayer exciter circuit base voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/331715/11683) for a full explanation, but you are basically abusing the transistor in two ways:

1. By leaving out the diode, you're forcing the B-E junction into reverse breakdown whenever the base tries to go negative.
2. The 2222 is a small transistor, only good for a few hundred milliwatts of dissipation. It's hard to say what this circuit needs, but it could be considerably more. And issue #1 is only making matters worse.

Comment: So the quick (before Feb 1st) solution is.....

Comment: What is the significance of Feb. 1? The first thing you should do is add the diode, assuming that wasn't totally clear in what I wrote above. If the transistor is still overheating after that, you need a bigger transistor -- one that can be bolted to a heatsink.

Comment: So the LED (Light Emitting Diode) will is actually doing something in the circuit other than indicating that the switch is on?  Feb 1st is when his project is due and I have been working on this for weeks now - using the wrong transistor and trouble shooting.  I just ordered a TIP31C transistor and a heatsink based on the above comments and others I found on this site.  I need a solution soon, unfortunately.

Comment: Update:  Added a bigger transistor T31C NPN and the LED to the circuit.  It WORKS!  Here is a short video. https://www.facebook.com/larry.reiter/videos/10155997926924705/